# Binding a native library in MonoTouch: works, but why strange results when subclassing? Missing NullAllowed attribute?

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, subclass

MonoTouch 5.2.13

I'm using a native ObjectiveC library via MonoTouch bindings. The library exposes a view controller. All is working fine, until I subclass the view controller. Then, I get NULL reference exceptions or part of the UI is not shown.

I have read about the problems with the btouch tool and the "-e" option. But from what I can see, the option is not present:

> Tool /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch execution started with
>   arguments: /d:DEBUG ApiDefinition.cs /s:StructsAndEnums.cs
>   /tmpdir:obj/Debug/ios/ /sourceonly:obj/Debug/ios//sources.list

The subclass does (in this example) not add any functionality, but using it is enough to break the binding:

```
// Works.
var contr = new NativeController();

// Fails with various errors. Throws a NULL reference exception about some UIPopoverController being NULL, for instance.
public class SubclassedController : NativeController
{
  public SubclassedController() : base()
  {
  }
}

var contr = new SubclassedController();
```

I figured out that adding the [NullAllowed] to a property solved the NULL reference exception.

The native controller exposes a property `(nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController`. This was bound as `UIPopoverController PopoveController {get; set;}` - adding the `NullAllowed` here solved the issue.

But now I'm facing issues with images not showing up and there is no obvious exception.

I assume these problems also derive from the fact that something is NULL when using the subclassed version but the native code seems to react on the NULL and handles it gracefully.

This leads to three questions:

- Why is the behavior different when using subclassing? What is MonoTouch doing to make this happen? Why do I get a NULL ref in the case I use a derived class? I'm not touching the UIPopoverController an either case.
- How can I find out what is wrong and how to fix it if there is no error?
- What else has to be taken care of, besides the NullAllowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific issue turned out to be two things:

- A missing `NullAllowed` attribute for a `UIPopoverController`
- A bug in MonoTouch 5.2.13 that is **not related to binding** but something else that has to do with CocoaTouch. The specific reason is unknown.

Everything is working as expected with MonoTouch 5.3.6

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the behavior different when using subclassing?

There can be several reasons, including the instance initializing itself differently based on it's class name. It's not hard to do in C# (very uncommon, inheritance is what's used) or Objective-C (delegates are often used to customize the behavior).

You'll need to refer to the [documentation](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation/Classes/PSPDFViewController.html), [header files](https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFKit-Demo/blob/master/PSPDFKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSPDFViewController.h#L325), [samples](https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFKit-Demo/tree/master/Examples/PSPDFKitExample) and product support of your native library to understand how subclassing works.

> What is MonoTouch doing to make this happen?

I do not think it's MonoTouch related. MonoTouch provides `btouch` to help you create bindings for Objective-C libraries. This is the **same** tool that Xamarin uses to make all iOS bindings.

Still unsure ? write a small Objective-C sample that does the same. Compare results with the MonoTouch version.

Different results ? Fill a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with both (C# and ObjC) test case and we'll check what's going on (as stated before we have good reasons to ensure that `btouch` is bug free ;-)

> Why do I get a NULL ref in the case I use a derived class? I'm not touching the UIPopoverController an either case.
>
> How can I find out what is wrong and how to fix it if there is no error?
>
> What else has to be taken care of, besides the NullAllowed?

At this stage you're running the native code of the library you binded. The *specific* rules you'll need to follow are the ones you'll find by:

- reading the library documentation;
- reading the library source (when available), headers and samples;
- for `[NullAllowed]` you can test (e.g. unit tests) if `null` is allowed or not (e.g. will it crash);

Also porting existing samples is both a good learning exercise (of the library API) and a quick way to test for bindings bugs (e.g. typos in selectors, wrong parameters...).

Comment: Hi sebastien and thanks for your response, im a new with unit test could you elaborate or point me on how to implement this??

Comment: Ok, found a very useful document -> http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Unit_Testing should have looked firs hehe

Comment: @dalexsoto That's not a good place to answer this. I replied to the original email thread, see: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2012-August/011503.html

Comment: So you're saying the NULL ref  is a different issue than the unexpected behavior, like missing images. The latter one seems impossible to figure out without support or the source code. To be honest: I haven't tried yet if subclassing is working in the ObjC version.

Comment: It could be the same *logical* reason, i.e. specific requirements to subclass. While I doubt it's the same *physical* (code) reason it's possible that the *same* solution (e.g. *correct* subclassing) would solve both.

Comment: @poupou I have just figured out the the issue only occurs in MT 5.2.13 but not in 5.3.6...I'll investigate and submit a bug or contact you via email.